# How do I add a new associative array key to a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, session, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to add a new value called "name" to the associative array called "company_*," which is one of five companies stored in the "result" associative array as the result of a MySQL query.

I *suspect* that setting each company as a local variable in the foreach doesn't update the inner array values of $result, but I can't find a solution. Below is the code I'm using to do the task:

```
$member_id = $_SESSION['member_id']; // The member_id of who is logged in
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM member_answers WHERE member_id = '$member_id'")) {

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 5) {
      $result = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      // Let's also set up company names by querying for the company name in the DB
      foreach ($result as $company) {
        $tempID = $company['company_id'];
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM companies WHERE company_id = `$tempID` LIMIT 1");
        $name = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $company['name'] = $name[0];
      }

      // Set up the session variables
      $_SESSION['company_one'] = $result[0];
      $_SESSION['company_two'] = $result[1];
      $_SESSION['company_three'] = $result[2];
      $_SESSION['company_four'] = $result[3];
      $_SESSION['company_five'] = $result[4];
      $_SESSION['all_companies'] = $result;
      $_SESSION['chosen_companies'];
```

Comment: if you want to make changes in the original array just use the reference in company `$result as &$company`

Comment: What's the difference between &$company and $company?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: That worked! I also found that mixing the procedural style mysqli_fetch_row() versus $query->fetch_row() was giving me issues as well. Thanks.